# Consulta que no incluya un registro determinado

Tags: mysql

Tengo que hacer un `select` de la `tbl_libros` donde tengo una relación uno a muchos con otra tabla llamada `categorias`. Necesito hacer un `select` de esos libros mientras que dentro de la `tbl_categoria` NO tenga una categoría determinada.

Debo cargar un Array con todos los libros que dentro de su relación con `tbl_categoria` no tenga una llamada `ninguna` que su `id` es el `1`.

Problé con un simple `categoriaId!=1` pero me funciona siempre y cuando el libro no tenga otras categorías. Espero explicarme !

Intenté con subconsultas, con `NOT IN`, pero llego siempre al mismo resultado. Tengo la tabla `libros` y la tabla `libros_categorias` donde tengo las columnas `idlibro` e `idCategoria`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT * FROM libros,libros_categorias
  WHERE libros.id=idlibro
  AND idCategoria!=1
  ORDER BY nombre;
```

El `libro 2` no me lo muestra que es el que yo quiero, pero porque tiene esa única categoría, pero el `libro 1` si me lo muestra porque tiene más categorías aparte de `ninguna`, y necesito que tampoco lo muestre.

Comment: Muestra la estructura de las tablas, la consulta que estás intentando, el resultado que obtienes y el que esperas obtener. Convendría también ver un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable que incluya un pequeño set de datos. Sin ver tu escenario no podremos ayudarte. Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: buenas a ver como le hago por que yo lo simplifique tengo varias tablas y es muy larga la consulta pero te agrego un cudro simplificado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esto te funciona:

```
Select * from libros
where id not in 
(select idlibro 
from libros_categorias 
where idcategoria = 1)
order by nombre;
```

Primero tomas los ids de libros en esa categoria 1 y luego lees todos los libros que no tengan la categoría 1

Comment: ¿Cómo es posible validar una respuesta sin haber probado el código? Esta consulta tiene una errata y no puede funcionar: la tabla `libros` no contiene el campo `idlibro`, sino `id`

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta consulta debes pensar en conjuntos.

En el primer paso ver qué libros tienen la categoría 1:

```
SELECT idlibro
  FROM libros_categorias
  WHERE idCategoria=1
```

Y quedarte con aquellos libros que no estén en ese conjunto:

```
SELECT * FROM libros
  WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT idlibro
      FROM libros_categorias
      WHERE idCategoria=1  
  );
```

Este sería tu dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE libros(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE categorias(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  categoria varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE libros_categorias(
  idCategoria int,
  idlibro int,
  FOREIGN KEY(idCategoria) REFERENCES categorias(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(idlibro) REFERENCES libros(id)
  );
INSERT INTO libros (nombre) VALUES
  ('21 lecciones para el sigo XXI'),
  ('770 gramos');
INSERT INTO categorias (categoria) VALUES
  ('Ninguna'),('Historia');
INSERT INTO libros_categorias VALUES
  (1,2),(1,1),(2,1);
```

Verás que ningún libro lo cumple.

Añadamos un nuevo libro en la categoría 2:

```
INSERT INTO libros (nombre) VALUES
  ('La isla del tesoro');
INSERT INTO categorias VALUES
  (3,2);
```

El resultado que obtendrías sería:

```
+----+--------------------+
| id | nombre             |
+----+--------------------+
|  3 | La isla del tesoro |
+----+--------------------+
```

Comment: LIsto ahora si muchas gracias!

Comment: @SergioValdivia [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que debes seleccionar solamente los libros que no tengan la categoría 1 (Ninguna). Acá mi aporte

```
SELECT *
FROM   libros l
       INNER JOIN libros_categorias c ON
          l.id = c.idLibro
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT c2.idLibro
          FROM   libros_categorias c2
          WHERE  c2.idLibro = l.id
                 AND c2.idCategoria = 1
       )
```

En general, se recomienda el uso de `INNER JOIN` porque en caso de que hayan múltiples join con múltiples tablas aporta más claridad a la sentencia.